# Laravel SASS - Customize the INPUT Directory

Tags: css, laravel, sass, laravel-5.1

How can I change the input directory of SASS files in Laravel?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#sass

This works fine for when the files are in `/resources/assets/sass`

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass([
        'app.scss',
        'controllers.scss'
    ], 'public/assets/css');
});
```

But I want the input folder to be: `/resources/views/footer`

Comment: did you tried '../../views/footer/file.scss' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try changing so config settings:

```
 var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

 elixir.config.assetsPath = 'resources/views';
 elixir.config.css.sass.folder = 'footer';

 .....
```

But this will set the main resources folder for all/everything. So could try:

```
elixir.config.css.sass.folder = '../views/footer';
```

not near a machine to test.

Or you can set all the sections your using to their folders etc like:

```
 var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

 elixir.config.assetsPath = 'resources';
 elixir.config.css.sass.folder = 'footer';
 elixir.config.css.folder = 'assets/css';
 elixir.config.js.folder = 'assets/js';
```

And son on, to accommodate your request.